# TypeError: 'Vocab' object is not callable

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

I'm following the tutorial on [torchtext transformers](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transformer_tutorial.html) which is published on 1.9 pytorch. However, because I'm working on a Tegra TX2, I am stuck to using torchtext 0.6.0, and not 0.10.0 (which is what I assume the tutorial uses).

Following the tutorial, the following throws an error:

```
data = [torch.tensor(vocab(tokenizer(item)), dtype=torch.long) for item in raw_text_iter]
    return torch.cat(tuple(filter(lambda t: t.numel() > 0, data)))
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: 'Vocab' object is not callable
```

I understand what the error means, what I don't know, is that is the expected return from `Vocab` in this case?

Looking at the [documentation for TorchText 0.6.0](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/torchtext.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/vocab.html?highlight=build_vocab_from_iterator#) I see that it has:

- `stoi`
- `itos`
- `freqs`
- `vectors`

Is the example expecting the `vectors` from `Vocab`?

## EDIT:

I looked up the [0.10.0 documentation](https://pytorch.org/text/stable/vocab.html) and it doesn't have a `__call__`.

Comment: Please, always post the complete traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://pytorch.org/text/stable/_modules/torchtext/vocab.html#Vocab) for the implementation of `Vocab` in 0.10.0, apparently it is a subclass of `torch.nn.Module`, which means it inherits `__call__` from there (calling it is roughly equivalent to calling its `forward()` method, but with some additional machinery for implementing hooks and such).

We can also see that it wraps some underling `VocabPyBind` object (equivalent to the `Vocab` class in older versions), and its `forward()` method just calls its `lookup_indices` method.

So in short, it seems the equivalent in older versions of the library would be to call `vocab.lookup_indices(tokenizer(item))`.

**Update:** Apparently in 0.6.0 the `Vocab` class does not even have a `lookup_indices` method, but reading the source for that, this is just equivalent to:

```
[vocab[token] for token in tokenizer]
```

If you're ever able to upgrade, for the sake of forward-compatibility you could write a wrapper like:

```
from torchtext.vocab import Vocab as _Vocab

class Vocab(_Vocab):
    def lookup_indices(self, tokens):
        return [vocab[token] for token in tokens]

    def __call__(self, tokens):
        return self.lookup_indices(tokens)
```

Comment: It looks in 0.6.0 it does not even have `lookup_indices` though.  I was looking at the 0.8.0 code.  Not sure what the equivalent would be, but maybe you can at a minimum update to 0.8.0?

Comment: OMG you just made my day! :-) thank you so much, I wasn't expecting to be spoon fed the answer. So, basically, it's the `__getitem__` that gets called? No I can't upgrade to 0.8.0 because the TX2 is bound to arm64 code (although I haven't tried it). I suspect I'll need a wrapper for it.